# Why does one come to a "sticky end"?

Tags: etymology, expressions

I was reading this question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24326/what-does-the-kitten-get), and thinking, the kitten will come to a *sticky end*. But why is a ghastly but non-specific fate referred to as a *sticky end*? This source [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1966820) suggests that blood is involved, but surely there's more to it than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partridge gives this derivation chain:

> **sticky**, *adj.* (Of persons) wooden, dull; awkward: 1881, Mrs Lynn Linton (O.E.D.). Ex *stick*, a dull person.—2. (Of stock) not easy to sell: Stock Exchange: 1901, *The Times, Oct. 24 (O.E.D.) : > by 1920, coll Cf. *sticker*, 1. q.v.—3. (Of persons) not easy to interview; unpleasant and/or obstinate; difficult to placate: from ca. 1919. Ex :—4. Of situation, incident, work, duty : unpleasant; very difficult : 1915 ('A sticky time in the trenches': O.E.D. Sup.); T. S. Eliot, in *Time and Tide*, Jan. 5, 1935, '[St Thomas of Canterbury] **came to a sticky end.' This sense derives prob. ex senses 1 and 2 + S.E.** (? orig.—1989—coll.) *sticky*, (applied to troops) apt to hesitate in obeying commands (O.E.D., adj., 2, 949 §2, b).
>   *[Emphasis added]*

Comment: Neat. The phrase in my mind seems to be used with, at least, some humor today. Perhaps, by people thinking that it was related to the sticky 'goo' of a mangled body, and reserving it for a more light, or comic death.

Answer (score 0):

Bodies of wealthy people who died far from home, usually senior officers in wars, were preserved in honey and shipped home to be buried.

Comment: Do you have any citations/references for this, and whether this is actually where the phrase is derived from?